# href to 7z archive displaying contents in browser rather then download

Tags: html

I have a link on my website to a 7z archive, but when I and my few users click the link in FireFox, it opens a text view of the file in the browser.

```
EG: 7z��'�^�j�t������#�������葰����&�N�חa�����O��db�~��K����Ҍ2�|qi�铄��[�
```

I have checked my FireFox -> Application settings, and 7zip is set to always ask.

here is my page code:

```
<table class="main" width="100%" height="10" cellpadding=10>
    <tr>
        <td class="thintext_grey" valign="top" align=right height=10>
        DOWNLOAD IT :: <a href="imgGet5000_v1.7z"> imgGet5000 v1 </a><br>
        Written in Python <br>
        Completed and added on 2012-08-15 by Jimmy <br>
        <hr size=1>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Could be your server isn't properly cuing the browser as to what kind of file it's receiving.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `Content-Type` header coming from your server is incorrect.  You need to change your server's configuration so that it uses this for `.7z` files:

```
application/x-7z-compressed
```

You can easily verify this problem using your browser's built-in tools, or something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: I added " AddType application/x-7z-compressed 7z " to httpd.conf and restarted the apache instance. Working perfectly. TY very much.